# Nothing work after suspend / Sleep, can't even reboot

Tags: keyboard, suspend, reboot, sleep

I pressed the suspend button and now my computer is useless, my screen won't turn on, my keyboard and mouse have power but won't do anything. I tried pressing the power button in order to awake my PC but it did nothing, i also tried a reboot but nothing changed... I can't use anything... How do i fix this problem?

Any help be greatly appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do a hard shut down on your computer you have to keep the power button pressed for like 5 seconds.

If you wan to reboot it making sure that the potential damage is minimized you can press this key combo:

> Ctrl+Alt+Prnt Scr

and holding these keys pressed type the following letters '`reisub`'

With that your computer should reboot safely.

Comment: the `Alt+ SysRsq ` combinations and sequences like `reisub` work when the kernel has control. In most cases of resume failure i came across, Kernel doesn't get the control yet, i.e, b4 the system 'hangs' and so this wont work. Hard reboot is all you are left with.